# JMeter: What could be possible reason of same throughput though user load has increased

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

What could be the possible reason for throughput remaining the same though load has increased much compared to previous tests? NOTE: I even received the error "`Internal Server Error`" while running my performance test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have reached the **Saturation Point** - the point for maximum performance!

A certain amount of concurrent users adjoining with maximum CPU utilization and peak throughput. Adding any more concurrent users will lead to degradation of response time and throughput, and will cause peak CPU utilization. Also, it can throw some errors!

After that, If you continue increasing the number of virtual users you may see these:

- Response time is increasing.
- Some of your requests got failed.
- Throughput is either remains the same or decreases - this indicates the [performance bottleneck](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/techniques-performance-bottleneck-analysis-dheeraj-reddy-dega)!

Comment: got it!!..Thankyou so much for your help and answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ideal load test in ideal world looks like:

- response time remains the same, not matter how many virtual users are hitting the server
- throughput increases by the same factor as the load increases, i.e:

  - 100 virtual users - 500 requests/second
  - 200 virtual users - 1000 requests/second
  - etc.

In reality application under test might [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing) up to certain extent, but finally you will reach the point when you will be increasing the load but the response time will be going up and throughput will remain the same (or going down)

Looking into [HTTP Status Code 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Most probably it indicates the fact that the application under test is overloaded, the next step would be to find out the reason which may be in:

1. Application is not properly [configured for the high loads](https://stackify.com/web-performance-optimization/) (including all the middleware: application server, database, load balancer, etc.)
2. Application lacks resources (CPU, RAM, etc.), can be checked using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
3. Application uses [inefficient functions/algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), can be checked using [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools)